# Memory Leak in Java, Out of Heap Memory not related to Heap Size

Tags: java, memory, memory-leaks

[image]My Program ran into out of heap space error. I increased the size of the heap but it didn't help.
After profiling the program, I have received the result and which implies 37.8% of heap memory is consumed by Integer.parseInt(String). I am using Integer.parseInt(String) rigorously in my program because of my assumption it returns primitive and collected by GC. But, it isn't happening. Can anyone shed some light on why this behavior usually occurs?[image]

Comment: Dumb question, but are you sure you did a memory profile and not a performance one? That would make the `parseInt` result make a lot more sense.

Comment: Added another snapshot, showing the profiler. I hope you will understand what I am trying to ask why primitive types are not collected by GC. Is there any best way to approach the memory leak?

Comment: Primitive types are not collected by GC because the GC only collects objects. The first screenshot shows that somehow your program keeps 235,392 `java.lang.Integer` objects - probably due to adding them into some `java.util.ArrayList`s (of which there are 191,830 instances)

Comment: Since you are using JProfiler, take a heap snapshot in the heap walker and go to the "Biggest objects" view. That view is likely to show you what is holding on to all those objects.